# Having trouble with XML and AS3, is there something wrong with my XML file? (XML parser failure: element is malformed.)

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

Okay,

So I'm making a flash appication that has some thumbnail buttons that need to play different videos when they are clicked. I keep getting the error:

TypeError: Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.

```
at MediaPlayer2_fla::MainTimeline/xmlLoadedVid()[MediaPlayer2_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:25]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

I presume this means there is something wrong with the XML file rather than my AS3 code, but I can't figure out what it is.

The AS3 looks like this:

```
var vidList_XML:XML;
var vidNum:int = 0;
var currVid:String;
var vidLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

vidLoader.load(new URLRequest("/ASSETS/XML/vidlist.xml"));
vidLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoadedVid);

function xmlLoadedVid(e:Event):void{
    vidList_XML = new XML(vidLoader.data);

    vid1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pickVid);   

    //vidPlayer.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, nextVid);
    //vidPlayer.source = vidList_XML.vid[vidNum].file;


    }



function pickVid(e:MouseEvent):void {
    switch (e.currentTarget.name){
        case "vid1":
            vidNum = 0;
        currVid = vidList_XML.vid[vidNum].file;     

        break;
        }

        var uiRequestVid: URLRequest = new URLRequest(currVid);
        vidLoader.load(uiRequestVid);
        }
```

and the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<videos>

    <vid>
        <file>ASSETS/MOVIES/vid1.mp4</file>
        <name> 1 </name>
    </vid>

  <vid>
    <file>ASSETS/MOVIES/vid2.mp4</file>
    <name> 2 </name>
    </vid>

  <vid>
    <file>ASSETS/MOVIES/vid3.mp4</file>
    <name> 3 </name>
    </vid>

  <vid>
    <file>ASSETS/MOVIES/vid4.mp4</file>
    <name> 4 </name>
    </vid>

  <vid>
    <file>ASSETS/MOVIES/vid5.mp4</file>
    <name> 5 </name>
    </vid>

  <vid>
    <file>ASSETS/MOVIES/vid6.mp4</file>
    <name> 6 </name>
    </vid>

</videos>
```

any help would be great!

Comment: XML data is fine, you should trace the raw loaded data **vidLoader.data** and see if it is indeed your XML data and not some error text or null.

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working, turns out the issue was something completely unrelated! :)